# How can some kids in Dragon Ball Super are younger than in Dragon Ball Z?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

If *Dragon Ball Super* is a direct sequel from *Dragon Ball Z*, how are some of the kids younger there?

Examples

| Character | DBZ | DB Super |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Marron | [image] | [image] |
| Bura/Bra | [image] | [image] |
| Goten and Trunks | [image] | [image] |
| Pan | [image] | [image] |

Did they forget about it?

Comment: I see, so db super is not a sequel